# Partner Community How to stop users seeing ALL other portal users

Tags: partner-portal, community

Setting up a Partner Community Portal and struck a big security challenge that I need your help with.

In the old partner portal environment there was no chatter available, so sharing was pretty straight forward in that you could limit visibility of info to those records owned by users from the same account. No drama there.

The issue is now however that using partner community product, **if I log in as a portal user I can view ALL other portal users including those from other partners** by just clicking All Users link in Chatter tab.  Surely there is a way I could restrict a partner users options to only those users from same account? Any suggestions most appreciated!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

See the Winter '14 release notes about the new User Sharing feature. You will need to make users private and create sharing rules for internal users:

https://help.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_winter14_release_notes.pdf

This will enable you to restrict visibility of users within a community.

Comment: I'll take that as a solution - and also add the note that in sharing Settings panel admin needs to ensure the 'Community User Visibility' setting is set to false.